# Automate SSHing into multiple connections with script

Tags: shell-script, ssh, ssh-tunneling

I want to ssh through three different servers. First one uses a password, second one doesn't and the third and final one has a different password than the first. Only the first one needs a username.

What I've been doing is something like this:

```
ssh user@hosname1
- enter password
ssh hostname2
ssh hostname3
-enter new password
```

Is there any way to automate this with a bash script that I can run? I don't think I can use ssh-key based authentication.

Comment: There is a tool called sshpass that can be used to pass passwords through various means, useful in scripting.  However key based auth is much more secure

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the "ProxyJump" directive in ssh_config or the -J option on the ssh command. You can use it to jump through multiple servers to get to your final destination

ssh -J user@hostname1,user@hostname2 user@hostname3